# Display AddressBook contacts doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am fetching my iOS **Address Book contacts** and I store them in an Array called `contacts[]`.

Here is my method:

```
 var contacts: [String] = []

 func getContactNames() {
    if !self.determineStatus() {
        println("not authorized")
        return
    }
    let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(adbk).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
    for person in people {
        self.contacts.append(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue())
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, I display them in a nice `UITableView`. It works well in the Simulator (iOS 8.1) but not on my iPhone.
On my phone I got the famous error:

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The thing is I am not using optionals here. After different test it turns out that I get this error only if my contact list has more than 26 contacts.

Weird, 26 is also the number of letter in the Alphabet so I am searching in that direction.

Do you have any clue? I would appreciate your help. Thank you

PS: In the debug screen it seems that it's coming from this line:

```
let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(adbk).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
```

Comment: Any findings? Have the same issues

Comment: With iOS9 the way you can browse contacts changed totally. There is a new framework called Contacts, it replace the old Address Book framework. [Doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompose this line to single statements and check which one is causing trouble.

E.g:

`let a = adbk
    let b = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(adobe)
    let c = b.takeRetainedValue()
    let d = c as [ABRecord]`

Check each variable and you'll find it :)

In Swift you can also declare variables as [Implicitly unwrapped optional type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1129) which is declared as `let a: Type!` (with exclamation mark). It basically means that variable can be nil (you don't need to initialize it in constructor) but you guarantee that during lifetime of the app it will never contain nil. This mechanism is introduced mainly to maintain Objective-C compatibility but it sometimes causes some unexpected `nil` related errors.